# ImageMagick and PNG

Tags: linux, imagemagick, png

I'm trying to install ImageMagick but everytime, the `libpng` isn't used.

When I'm running

```
identify -version
```

`png` does not appear in the list.

I'm retrying to install properly ImageMagick with these commands:

```
./configure --enable-shared
make libdir=/usr/lib64
make libdir=/usr/lib64 install
./configure --enable-shared=yes --x-libraries=/usr/lib64 --without-perl
make
make install
```

after in found `libpng` in `/usr/lib64` on my system.

But after

```
make libdir=/usr/lib64 install
```

I always have this

```
 DELEGATES       = bzlib mpeg freetype jpeg lcms ps tiff x zlib
```

and no `png` is listed.

I'm still in trouble. I don't know where is my mistake.

I'm working on CentOS 6.6.

Comment: Which distro are you using? My precompiled Slackware package comes with **two** png: `Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lzma openexr pango pangocairo png png rsvg tiff x xml zlib`, but I can't find the compilation options.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini: you can query ImageMagick for its compilation/build-time settings: `convert -list configure`. It will tell you exactly which `./configure` options were used before building the binaries.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle thanks for the tip! If this can help Kzoo to solve his problem, I have `CFLAGS -pthread -I/usr/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/include/freetype2 -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686 -Wall -pthread` and `CONFIGURE ./configure  '--prefix=/usr' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--mandir=/usr/man' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--program-prefix=' '--with-x' '--with-frozenpaths=no' '--without-modules' '--disable-openmp' '--enable-static=no' '--enable-shared' '--with-perl' '--with-rsvg' '--build=i486-slackware-linux' 'build_alias=i486-slackware-linux' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Try to add `--with-modules` to your configure options.
2. Also, inspect the output of your `./configure ...` command for error and warning messages.
3. Most Linux distros package the runtime libraries separately from the compile-time header files. You may need to install an additional package named `libpng-dev` or `libpng-devel` to get the header files onto your system which are needed to compile ImageMagick with PNG support.